# Реализовать отправку письма без открытия сокета

Tags: c#, winforms

Возможно ли(и если возможно то как) реализовать отправку письма без "открытия сокета" средствами c# в приложении WinWorms?

Comment: [MailKit](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Getting-Started.htm)?

Comment: @VladD возможно, что это? dll библиотека?

Comment: Это библиотека, и вроде бы очень популярная. Я сам никогда не пользовался, а то бы написал ответ. Но там вроде бы есть хорошие примеры в документации.

Comment: [Вот тут](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Frequently-Asked-Questions.htm) примеры кода с отправкой сообщений.